# use of “except” in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "except" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? Is the following sentences correct grammatically?If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> As discussed previously, there are another kind of losses in Wells
>   turbine **except** loss due to blade profile. These losses are secondary
>   flows and Fig. 11 highlights the main secondary flow structures in
>   Wells turbine such as tip leakage vortex and horse-shoe vortices near
>   the hub (endwall boundary layer flow).

Comment: This was written poorly. What is the source? "there are another kind of losses"?? As it is, in place of *except* I would use *excepting*.

Answer (score 2):

For this use, I would choose `besides`.  You are not excluding blade profile loss as important--you are writing about other losses.  Another option would be `apart from`.

Also, I'd correct the bolded parts as well for plurality agreement, independent clauses, and article usage.   Not knowing your domain, I am unsure of styles particular to it, but some of the structure was a bit confusing:

> As discussed previously, there **is** another kind of **loss** in **the** Wells turbine **besides** loss due to blade profile. These losses are secondary **flows.** Figure 11 highlights the main secondary flow structures in Wells **turbines** such as **a** tip leakage vortex and horse-shoe vortices near the hub (endwall boundary layer flow).

It is also common to reorder the sentence to use `other than`, but I prefer the above.

> As discussed previously, **other than** loss due to blade profile, there is another kind of loss in the Wells turbine.

Or you might want to simplify by dropping unnecessary parts, making it more terse and introducing the main point (secondary flows) in the first sentence:

> Besides loss due to blade profile, the Wells turbine has losses due to secondary flows.

Comment: Someone needs to sort out the plurality there! You've changed OP's *there are another kind of losses* to *...another kind of **loss***, but the problem remains that we're talking about a singular ***kind*** of loss, so it should be *there **is** another kind of loss* (or *there **are other kinds** of loss/es*).

Comment: Yes, meant to fix that one too.  Now I have.